# I have a problem with function composite.

Tags: functions

I have a problem with the solution to an exercise of function composite.

- X = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
- f = 4, 8,-1, 4, 7, 6, 0

and

- X = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
- g = 7, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Write the sum of all values of x that the composition g∘f is not determined. In case there is no such values, write -1.

my solution is :
(g∘f)(x) = g(f(x))

then:

- g(f(1))=> g(4)= 2
- g(f(2))=> g(8) = -1
- g(f(3))=> g(-1) = -1
- g(f(4))=> g(4)= 2
- g(f(5))=> g(7)= 5
- g(f(6))=> g(6)= 4
- g(f(7))=> g(0) =-1

Sum = 2 + (-1)+(-1) + 2 + 5 + 4 + (-1) = 10.

but  the platform say that my answer is not correct

Comment: I believe you have to sum all $x$ values for which there's no definition: 8, -1, 0?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `calculus`?